# Obtaining Standard Error of Weighted Averages using Bootstrapping?

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error

My problem is finding a way to estimate the standard error of a flow-weighted mean concentration. The FWMC is computed by summing the years flow * concentration measurements and dividing by the sum of flow measurements (17 measures of paired concentration and flow for the year).  This FWMC number (in mg/L) is then multiplied by the known total volume of water in the stream to arrive at an estimate of the total mass of pollution.

I have yet to find a method which accounts for the dependence of mass on flow. Is there a way to do this in R via bootstrapping?

Data:

```
Phosphorus (ug/L)   Flow (L/sec)    Phosphorus *Flow (ug/sec)   
44.5    424.752699  18890.13722 
39.6    311.4853126 12324.55805 
41.7    87.78222446 3664.848179 
29.9    226.5347728 6768.125039 
43.1    254.8516194 10994.0542  
51.6    192.5545569 9928.871618 
91.6    53.80200854 4930.741027 
265.4   11.32673864 3005.662573 
85.8    155.7426563 13363.84022 
66.6    175.5644489 11699.2181  
41.6    226.5347728 9417.440145 
32.2    283.168466  9116.450189 
36.8    150.079287  5525.724244 
40.5    158.574341  6421.823144 
29.4    368.1190058 10811.05885 FWMC
sum 3080.87291  136862.5528 44.42330365
```